# same verb Http in controller different endpoint Sails routes

Tags: controller, routes, sails.js

I have a problem with sails, when I make the endpoints.

I have in my route this

```
'get /user': 'UserController.find',
'get /user/:name': 'UserController.findByName',
```

and two endpoints in the User controller

```
find: function(req,res,next){
        res.status(200);
        res.json("find");
},
findByName: function(req,res){
        res.status(200);
        res.json("findByName");
}
```

I'm using postman for my test, when I make the request to `localhost:1337/user/findByName` the api return me

> findByName (correct)

The problem is when I make the request to `localhost:1337/user/find` the api return me

> findByName too (incorrect :( )

Why? I know that if the same http verb, get, but I'm refering to different endpoint. why it only return me findByName?.

Looks like the call make the request, but only it can see `findByName`.

Sorry for the bad English. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assue you misunderstood the resolving of the routes parameters.

With your routes config you should send requests like this:

**find**

`GET localhost:1337/user`
*- will go to find action in the controller.*

**findByName**

`GET localhost:1337/user/name`
*- will go to findByName action in the controller.*

Have a look at the [docu](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/routes). Also consider using the [blueprint routes and action](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api), which have find and findOne already implemented.